# Node js and socket io - appointment system

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm building pretty simple appointment system with node js, js and sql.
im getting the data: name, hour, day -> store it in sql (sending sms to the client) and edit the day and hour in the sql so it will not show it on the website.
everything is working well.
now i want that when some user made appointment it will show to other users that this hour in this day is not available (right now it is happening but the other users should refresh the page to see the update).
i think socket io can help me here.
i read all the documentation and its all about chat rooms.. before i get my hands dirty with socket io and trying to modify it, i want to ask for help . do you think it is possible to do it? and if yes what is the best way for your opinion.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You definitely can use WebSocket API (or any library built on top of it, e.g. Socket.io) to update a client's webpage without it having to refresh the page.
You could simply emit an event from your NodeJS application on receiving an an appointment request and handle the event's payload at the client's end to update the webpage.

Comment: ok, thank you very much it sounds good and simple i will try it.